# Python can't open file when running with ros

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.

I have a simple pygame script that shows some images on screen. The script works when I run it with python, but once I run it with ROS (rosrun or roslaunch) pygame can't open some files. I'm thinking this has something to do with the permissions of the file, but I don't know how to fix this.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kwint/catkin_ws/src/rolly/src/main.py", line 30, in <module>
    pygame.mixer.music.load(src_dir + "/" + 'beep.ogg')
pygame.error: Couldn't open '~/catkin_ws/src/rolly/src/beep.ogg'
```

The same error occurs when loading images

Although I don't think the error is in my code, the script can be read here: https://github.com/kwint/TrashNodes/blob/master/rolly/src/main.py

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313262/python-can%27t-open-file-when-running-with-ros/) by [kwint](https://answers.ros.org/users/34217/kwint/) on ROS Answers with karma: 55 on 2019-01-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, but I don't believe you can actually use `~` in filepaths in Python. That is a bash-ism (ie: only works within `bash`).

Try `os.path.expanduser(..)`.

`rosrun` / `roslaunch` don't change anything here afaict.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwint](https://answers.ros.org/users/34217/kwint/) on 2019-01-21**:
That did the trick! Weird that when running a script with just python the `~` does work, but with ros not.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-21**:\

> [..] with ros not.

"with ROS" makes little sense: in the end `rosrun` and `roslaunch` just call (via `Popen(..)` most likely) `python`, just as you do.

What *could* be a difference is the shell that is used, but I'm not sure.

Does it fail when you do `sh python /path/to/your/script.py`?

**Comment by [kwint](https://answers.ros.org/users/34217/kwint/) on 2019-01-21**:
Yes that's it. The same error occurs when I start it with `sh`. I didn't receive errors before because I was using `bash`. Thanks for making me understand this a bit more!